# Upgrading from React Navigation V4 to V5 redux integration

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I have just been given a project and I have been told to upgrade all the packages. Currently I am trying to upgrade react-navigation from V4 to V5 but I have hit a road block, I cannot figure out how to refractor the code at the end in `router.js`, or the code in `ReduxNavigation.js` and `Reducers/NavigationReducer.js`

old router.js (code moved into `app.tsx` below)

```
const defaultNavigationOptions = {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: ComponentStyles.Navigation.header,
    }
}

const modalNavigatorConfig = {
cardStyle: {
    opacity: 1
},
navigationOptions: {
    initialRouteName: 'Authentication',
    headerMode: 'screen'
}
```

}

```
const authStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Login: LoginScreen,
    }, defaultNavigationOptions
)

const dashboardStack = createStackNavigator({
    Dashboard: DashboardScreen,
}, defaultNavigationOptions)

const appStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Dashboard: {
        screen: dashboardStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: "Dashboard",
            tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintColor}) => (
                <Image
                resizeMode='contain'
                style={{width: 24, height: 24, tintColor: (focused ? null : tintColor) }}
                source={require('@Images/tab-dashboard.png')}
                />
            )
        }
    },
})

export const ModalStack = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        Authentication: authStack,
        App: appStack,
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Login',
        ...defaultNavigationOptions
    }
)

// Unsure of how to refractor this in V5 <---------------------

export const ReactNavigationReduxMiddleware = createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware(
    state => state.nav
)

export const App = createReduxContainer(ModalStack, 'root')
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    state: state.nav
})
const AppWithNavigationState = connect(mapStateToProps)(App)

export default AppWithNavigationState
```

App.tsx (router is in app.tsx as I couldn't figure out how to put it in a seperate router.js file)

```
const appStack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function appStack() {
    return (
        <appStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Authentication">
            <appStack.Screen name="Authentication" component={AuthLoadingScreen} options={{headerShown: false}} />
            <appStack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{headerShown: false}} />
            <appStack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={DashboardScreen} />
        </DashboardStack.Navigator>
    );
}

function TabsStack() {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Dashboard"
                component={appStack}
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
                    ),
                }}
            />
        )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
            <NavigationContainer>
                <TabsStack />
            </NavigationContainer>
        </Provider>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I am unsure of how to refractor this. Is it even possible in V5?

ReduxNavigation.js

```
class ReduxNavigation extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.onBackPress);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.onBackPress);
    }

    onBackPress = () => {
        const { nav, dispatch } = this.props;
        if (nav.index === 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if (nav.routes) {
            const currentRouteName = nav.routes[nav.index].routeName;
            if (currentRouteName === 'PAudit' || currentRouteName === 'PInit') {
                return true;
            }
        }
        dispatch(NavigationActions.back());
        return true;
    };

    render() {
        const { nav, dispatch } = this.props;
        return <App state={nav} dispatch={dispatch} />;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    nav: state.nav
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxNavigation);
```

Reducers/NavigationReducer.js (getActionForPathAndParams is deprecated in V5 and I cant find a similar function)

```
import { ModalStack } from '@Components/Router'

const { router } = ModalStack

const firstAction = router.getActionForPathAndParams('Authentication') // getActionForPathAndParams is deprecated in V5
const tempNavState = router.getStateForAction(firstAction)

/* ------------- Initial State ------------- */
export const INITIAL_STATE = router.getStateForAction(tempNavState)

export const reducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    const nextState = router.getStateForAction(action, state)

    // Simply return the original `state` if `nextState` is null or undefined.
    return nextState || state
}

export default reducer
```

Store

```
export default store = Reactotron.createStore(
    rootReducer,
    {},
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk),
        applyMiddleware(ReactNavigationReduxMiddleware)
    )
)
```

Reducers/index.js

```
const appReducer = combineReducers({
    nav: NavigationReducer,
})

const { Types, Creators: Actions } = createActions({
    resetApp: []
})

const rootReducer = createReducer([], {
    [Types.RESET_APP]: (state, action) => {
        return appReducer(undefined, action)
        //Passing undefined as state will make all the reducers using their initial states.
    },
    [ReduxSauceTypes.DEFAULT]: (state, action) => {
        return appReducer(state, action)
    }
})

const resetReduxStore = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(Actions.resetApp())
    }
}

export { rootReducer, resetReduxStore }
```

package.json

```
"react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
"react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^4.0.1",
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.2",
"react-navigation-tabs": "^2.10.1",
"redux": "^4.0.1",
"react-redux": "^7.2.2",
"redux-persist": "^5.6.6",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
"reduxsauce": "^0.7.0",
```

Comment: There is a lot of code here, but it would be helpful if you could explain what goals you are trying to achieve by integrating Redux and React Navigation rather than using the two independently.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I am new to React. I was just told to upgrade the package. I didnt write the original code. Is it better to use them independently? Whats the difference?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer for how to store your navigation state in redux is **DON'T**.

The current version of React Navigation makes this really explicit

> **Can I store the navigation state in Redux too?**
>
> This is not possible. We don't support it because it's too easy to shoot yourself in the foot and slow down / break your app.

They offer [some advice](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/redux-integration) about using values from redux to pass arguments to the `navigate` function.

What you are seeing in your code is something that was a feature of old versions of React Navigation but it was always advised against.  Even the [version 1.x docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/1.x/redux-integration/) say

> **Warning!**
>
> You probably do not need to do this! Storing your React Navigation state in your own Redux store is likely to give you a very difficult time if you don't know what you're doing. You lose out on some performance optimizations that React Navigation can do for you, for example. Please do not integrate your state into Redux without first ensuring that you can do what you need to do without it!

You will need to find any places in your app that are accessing a navigation state from redux and refactor them to access it directly from React Navigation using props and hooks.